# Salesforce Visualforce Button Redirect with parameters

Tags: visualforce

I have a button, which opens visualforce page which looks like that:

```
<apex:page controller="..." action={!methodName}">
</apex:page>
```

I click this button on Quote record, can I pass the ID of Quote somehow or any other field?

Answer (score 0):

Use standardController plus extension:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="..." action={!methodName}"></apex:page>
```

You'll need to add an appropriate constructor:

```
public class MyController {
  Id quoteId;
  public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    quoteId = controller.getId(); // has the quote id
  }
  public void methodName() {
    // You can use quoteId here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just figured out it is on CPQ Quote EDIT LINES, so it's not that simple since we don't have an access to ID over there in the CONFIGURATOR